# When I use middleware.BodyDumpConfig ERROR Response body object duplication problem

Tags: go, echo, middleware

I have problem in Golang echo framwork Error response like this.

{ERROR Response json struct}

`{"code":-208,"message":"Fail to login","internal":"{ERROR Message}","title":null,"btn_text":null} {"code":-208,"message":"Fail to login","internal":"{ERROR Message}","title":null,"btn_text":null}`

Whenever I use BodyDump, duplicate error responses are returned, but I can't find the reason.

Below is the source code of the body dump. I commented out all the actual use parts, but simply applying the body dump returns redundant json body data.

```
func MWBodyDumpForELS() echo.MiddlewareFunc {
    config := middleware.BodyDumpConfig{
        Skipper: middleware.DefaultSkipper,
        Handler: func(c echo.Context, reqBody, resBody []byte) {
            //session, _ := c.Get(SESSION_KEY).(*service.Session)
            //go els.Send(c.Path(), session.UserID, session.MembershipType, c.RealIP(), c.Request().RequestURI,
            //  c.Request().UserAgent(), c.Request().Method, c.Response().Header().Get("Content-Type"),
            //  c.QueryParams(), c.Response().Status, reqBody, resBody)
            return
        },
    }

    return middleware.BodyDumpWithConfig(config)
}
```

The HTTPErrorHandler I defined is It only seems to happen whenever it returns to that case.:

```
func HTTPErrorHandler(err error, c echo.Context) {
    // code := http.StatusInternalServerError
    switch t := err.(type) {
    case *echo.HTTPError:
        c.JSON(t.Code, NewAPIError(t.Code, fmt.Sprint(t.Message)).internal(t.Internal))
    case *APIError:
        c.JSON(t.httpCode, t)
    default:
        if err == nil {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, ErrUnknown)
        } else {
            c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, ErrUnknown.internal(err.Error()))
        }
    }
}
```

Someone know anything about this?